# Multi Database Migrations - How to set the connection details

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration, database-connection, multi-tenant

I'm creating a multi-tenant application with Laravel 4. At the moment I have two connections in my database.php

```
'connections' => array(
    'app' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'homestead',
        'username'  => 'homestead',
        'password'  => 'secret',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'tenant' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => '',
        'username'  => '',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )
```

When connecting to a tenant database in the application I call something like this:

```
$tenant = Tenant::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $tenant->db_username);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $tenant->db_password);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $tenant->db_database);
```

As you can see all my database names/connection details for tenants are set dynamically. 
this is an issue when i'm trying to run a migration as I can't find a way to set the connection details.

The only way I can do this at the moment is to call my migration from a controller. Is their a better way?